# Grid layout column span not works

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gridlayout

Grid layout column span not occupies 2 columns.All columns aligned on left in my android studio.In my case I have 4 columns and applied column span as 2 for all children.

```
<GridLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:columnCount="2"
        >
            <TextView
            android:text="title1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"

                />

            <TextView
                android:text="value1"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"

            />

            <TextView
                android:text="title2"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                 />



            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="title3"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />



            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="title4"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <EditText
                 android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="title5"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"

                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

                />
        </GridLayout>
```

In above code last two Edit text(title 4 & 5) are not align its width its parent.layout_width=match_parent not works here.

Comment: Do you really need to use GridLayout for this case? GridLayout uses a different approach when placing its children, comparing to LinearLayout and RelativeLayout.

Comment: @joao2fast4u I need to align a form.See my updated code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to accomplish what you are looking for. Just add layout_gravity and margin_right to your two last `EditTexts`, like this:

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

This will do the job.